# Python Response API JSON to CSV table

Tags: python, json, csv, python-requests, ibm-cloud

Bellow you see my code that I use to collect some data via the API of IBM. However I have some problems with saving the output via python to a csv table.

These are the columns that I want (and their values):

```
emotion__document__emotion__anger   emotion__document__emotion__joy
emotion__document__emotion__sadness emotion__document__emotion__fear    
emotion__document__emotion__disgust sentiment__document__score  
sentiment__document__label  language    entities__relevance 
entities__text  entities__type  entities__count concepts__relevance
concepts__text  concepts__dbpedia_resource  usage__text_characters
usage__features usage__text_units   retrieved_url
```

This is my code that I use to collect the data:

```
response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
  url=url,
  features=[
  Features.Emotion(),
  Features.Sentiment(),
  Features.Concepts(limit=1),
  Features.Entities(limit=1)
          ]
  )


data = json.load(response)
rows_list = []
cols = []

for ind,row in enumerate(data):

    if ind == 0:
        cols.append(["usage__{}".format(i) for i in row["usage"].keys()])
        cols.append(["emotion__document__emotion__{}".format(i) for i in row["emotion"]["document"]["emotion"].keys()])
        cols.append(["sentiment__document__{}".format(i) for i in row["sentiment"]["document"].keys()])
        cols.append(["concepts__{}".format(i) for i in row["concepts"].keys()])
        cols.append(["entities__{}".format(i) for i in row["entities"].keys()])
        cols.append(["retrieved_url"])

    d = OrderedDict()


    d.update(row["usage"])
    d.update(row["emotion"]["document"]["emotion"])
    d.update(row["sentiment"]["document"])
    d.update(row["concepts"])
    d.update(row["entities"])
    d.update({"retrieved_url":row["retrieved_url"]})

    rows_list.append(d)


df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
df.columns = [i for subitem in cols for i in subitem]
df.to_csv("featuresoutput.csv", index=False)
```

Changing

```
cols.append(["concepts__{}".format(i) for i in row["concepts"][0].keys()])
cols.append(["entities__{}".format(i) for i in row["entities"][0].keys()])
```

Did not solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

This line assigns a string to data:

```
data=(json.dumps(datas, indent=2))
```

So here you iterate over the characters of a string:

```
for ind,row in enumerate(data):
```

In this case `row` will be a string, and not a dictionary. So, for example, `row["usage"]` would give you such an error in this case.

Maybe you wanted to iterate over `datas`?

---

### Update

The code has a few other issues, such as:

```
cols.append(["concepts__{}".format(i) for i in row["concepts"].keys()])
```

In this case, you would want `row["concepts"][0].keys()` to get the keys of the first element, because `row["concepts"]` is an array.

I'm not very familiar with pandas, but I would suggest you to look at `json_normalize`, included in pandas, which can help flatten the JSON structure. An issue you might face, is the concepts and entities, which contain arrays of documents. That means that you would have to include the same document, at least `max(len(concepts), len(entities))` times.

Comment: Now I receive the error: "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'" after I removed datas and changed it to data and changed it to data = json.load(response). reponse here is the output of API.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I updated it. The output is 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Changed that, but  that did not solve the issue. I still receive the error AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'. (Another way to store the response as a csv then pandas is also fine for me)
After I updated changed         cols.append(["concepts__{}".format(i) for i in row["concepts"][0].keys()])
        cols.append(["entities__{}".format(i) for i in row["entities"][0].keys()])

Comment: Another question where should I add:  max(len(concepts), len(entities)) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you get it from an API, the response would be in json format. You can output it into a csv by:

```
import csv, json
response = the json response you get from the API
attributes = [emotion__document__emotion__anger, emotion__document__emotion__joy.....attributes you want]
data = json.load(response)
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for attribute in attributes:   
        writer.writerow(data[attribute][0])
    f.close()
```

make sure data is in dict but not string, Python 3.6 should return a dict. Print out a few rows to look into how your required data is stored.

Comment: Would this also work in python 2.7? Because I receive the message: attributes=[emotion__document__emotion__anger,   emotion__document__emotion__joy,
NameError: name 'emotion__document__emotion__anger' is not defined

Comment: attribute should be quoted as string, 'emotion__document__emotion__anger'

Comment: one trick that I have used for the Azure Face API, is `data = response.read()`, then `ast.literal_eval(data)` to make it into a python dict. Then based on the dictionary I can do things like `dictionary['isIdentical'] == True`

Comment: I still receive the same error after the adjustments I made: attributes='usage__text_units',  .... 'retrieved_url']

data = response.read()
ast.literal_eval(data)
dictionary['isIdentical'] == True

with open('0output.csv', 'w') as f:
...

Comment: that means you are still getting a string, not a dictionary, try to execute each line to see which goes wrong

Comment: I already get the error starting from data=response.read() where response is the output of the API: response = natural_language_understanding.analyze( url=url, features=[ Features.Emotion(), Features.Sentiment(), Features.Concepts(limit=1), Features.Entities(limit=1) ] ) attributes=['emotion__document__emotion__anger', 'usage__features', 'usage__text_units', 'retrieved_url'] data = response.read()